# MySQL, Can't create UNIX socket (12)

Tags: mysql

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2001] Can't create UNIX socket (12)
```

On my local machine my project works fine. As soon as I pushed my changes to the server I get this error message.

The mysql log is totally empty.

Mysql config: [my.cnf](http://dpaste.com/hold/765833/)

However another site that uses the same mysql server works fine.

---

Here are some more information: My vServer is running ubuntu 10.04 and has 2 GB of RAM.

```
/root$ ps -le | grep mysqld
0 S     0  9502     1  0  85   0 -  1025 wait   ?        00:00:00 mysqld_safe
4 S   109  9539  9502  0  76   0 - 77209 stext  ?        00:01:02 mysqld
/root$ ps -le | grep mysqld
0 S     0  9502     1  0  85   0 -  1025 wait   ?        00:00:00 mysqld_safe
4 S   109  9539  9502  0  75   0 - 77209 stext  ?        00:01:03 mysqld

/root$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 20
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 16382
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Maybe there is just to view ram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [CR_SOCKET_CREATE_ERROR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_socket_create_error), an error generated by the client code.

The 12 is probably your client's `errno`.  What is error 12 on your system?  For me, using the mysql `perror` command line utility, it's "OS error code  12:  Cannot allocate memory"

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, what does `"perror 12"` on the machine generating the error say?

Comment: It's "Cannot allocate memory"

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, that's your problem, then.  Again, this is a *client* error code, not a server error.

Comment: I optimized my code to reduce DB queries and take less memory, now it works. thank you

Comment: That's a great response and outcome; +1 to you @ArtWorkAD

Comment: Maybe this will help some guys who handle multiple db connections and got that Error. -> Check that your Application is not handling to much db-connections at one time! Its a code sided Problem!