# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2001): Can't create UNIX socket (12)

Tags: php, sockets, unix, mysqli

I have a problem with `mysqli` connection, in my project sometimes appears the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2001): Can't create UNIX socket (12)

line error code is as follows:

```
$this->cnx_ = mysqli_connect($this->server_, $this->user_, $this->pass_,$this->db_);
```

I searched about it and can't find the solution...

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL, Can't create UNIX socket (12)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297729/mysql-cant-create-unix-socket-12)